# PCL 4.6 .NET Framework need to use System.Security.Cryptography but can't

Tags: c#

I created a new PCL (Portable Class Library) and thus have targeted

```
.NET Framework 4.6
ASP.NET Core 5.0
```

My problem is I need to do a MD5 hash from:

`System.Security.Cryptography` but it claims that it doesn't exist. When I go over to the references and try to add it the area says "All of the framework assemblies are already referenced."

Is there no way to bring this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Security.Cryptography.Cng NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng/)

This package implements classes in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

[More information on **Cryptography API: Next Generation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376210(v=vs.85).aspx)

*as of November 2015, you need to check "Include prerelease" in the NuGet package manager.*